# Building a data subscriber. How to loop hopen through IPs

Tags: publish-subscribe, kdb, handle

I am trying to build a subscriber function that goes like this:

1. Every user register his machine name to a list using
   `hostname:enlist .z.h`
2. The function loops through the hostname list, creates connection and do some function `` {u:hopen(`:x:200;5000);u"somefunction[]"} each hostname ``

The only issue is .z.h is of a symbol where x should have no type in order to have this: `` u:hopen(`:HURNMW052:200;5000) `` instead of this `` u:hopen(`:`HURNMW052:200;5000) ``

The same thing happens using IPs `”.” sv string”h”$0x0 vs .z.a` = `"161.16.16.23"` not `161.16.16.23`

Any idea how I could cast those or other solutions to create a loop of handles?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a string to open a connection. See below.

```
q)":",string[.z.h],":8009"
":homer:8009"
q)h:hopen(":",string[.z.h],":8009";5000)
q)h
3i
```

This reference on the [kx wiki](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/hopen/) is useful for opening connections in kdb.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I was looking for!